# How can i select max of rows without using groupby in SQL code?

Tags: mysql, sql

[Please look at my question in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SThq1.png)

I created an sql code but the problem is ;

```
Column A    Column B     CreationDate        
1              50        2019-10-10 10:41
1              80        2019-10-10 10:43
1              70        2019-10-10 11:05  
2              60        2019-10-10 10:40       
2              58        2019-10-10 10:41
2              50        2019-10-10 10:44  
2              47        2019-10-10 11:00
```

By sorting, at the end I wanna see the data related to the latest Creation Date like:

```
Column A    Column B     CreationDate   
1              50        2019-10-10 11:05 
2              47        2019-10-10 11:00
```

Therefore i need to do some iterations in CreationDate column but i dont know how to do it in sql.

I cannot use groupby because Column B prevents it to do. This column is a forecast column which is created at CreationDate. Therefore, I just want to get the latest forecast.

Comment: Correction: At the end, for column 2 I need to see Creation Date as 2019-10-10 11:00

Please look at the photo that i attached to see my problem

Comment: Then edit your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want filtering.  I would write this as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.creation_date = (select max(t2.creation_date)
                         from t t2
                         where t2.a = t.a
                        );
```

If you really want to avoid aggregation functions (although there is no need to), here are three other ways:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.creation_date = (select t2.creation_date
                         from t t2
                         where t2.a = t.a
                         order by t2.creation_date desc
                         limit 1
                        );
```

And:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.creation_date >= all (select t2.creation_date
                              from t t2
                              where t2.a = t.a
                             );
```

And:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.creation_date > t.creation_date and
                        t2.a = t.a
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the RANK() function, e.g.

```
 ;WITH result as 
 ( SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, CreationDate, 
   RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ColumnA ORDER BY CreationDate DESC) as Rank
   FROM TableName
 )
 SELECT * FROM result WHERE Rank=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to only get rows for which no later row entry exists:

```
select *
from mytable m
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable m2
  where m2.column_a = m.column_a
  and m2.creationdate > m.creationdate
)
order by column_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sql I wrote for you:

```
SELECT 
    a.Column_A, a.Column_B, b.latest_date
FROM
    your_table a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        Column_A, max(CreationDate) AS latest_date
    FROM
        your_table
    GROUP BY Column_A) b 
ON a.Column_A = b.Column_A
WHERE a.Column_B = 50;
```

As your request changed, your expectation in your image was not the same as your description, if Column_B is fixed to 50, please try the sql above. if not, please try the sql below:

```
SELECT 
    a.Column_A, a.Column_B, b.latest_date
FROM
    your_table a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        Column_A, max(CreationDate) AS latest_date
    FROM
        your_table
    GROUP BY Column_A) b 
ON a.Column_A = b.Column_A
AND a.CreationDate = b.latest_date
```